# How can I have a listener on a MovieClip ignore other MovieClips inside of it when clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have various MovieClips that I want the player to click on:

```
var M:someObject= new someObject(); // someObject extends MovieClip
M.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
```

And this works fine.  The problem arises when I try to put animating MovieClips inside of M so I have a clean workspace apart from all the other Labesl and things I'm doing inside M.

For example, I put N inside of M (not through code but in the library).  Now when I click on M, flash thinks I'm clicking on N and doSomething() doesn't get called.

How can I make it so that clicking on the MovieClip OR any of its children will result in the same function being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable [`mouseChildren`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren).

> Determines whether or not the children of the object are mouse, or user input device, enabled.

```
M.mouseChildren = false;
```